# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android-studio

**I tried to build the first simple HelloWorld project on Android Studio in Windows 8:**

```
package com.samuel.helloworld;

/**
 * Created by Samuel on 5/16/13.
 */

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

**When run, got an exception error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.samuel.helloworld.HelloWorld

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

**What went wrong?**

Comment: That doesn't look to me like the structure of an android project :)

Comment: Android Studio seems to have problems with running plain Java projects. For me, it tries to load the class from `build/classes/production` which does not exist at all. I'm trying to get it to use the correct class path (`build/classes/main`) but no success yet.